# Tab responsiveness is much slower that with native Apps

Tags: java, javascript, android, gwt, mgwt

I built a couple of MGWT apps for iOs and Android.

To give the user some touch feedback we use the css :ACTIVE class.Compared with native Android or iOS app this is very slow.
What we found is that the it takes a couple of millisecond until the :ACTIVE event is triggered. This is much faster for native apps.

I use TouchPanels.

Is there a way to make the touch responsiveness faster with MGWT?

Comment: There may be a problem somewhere in your code that slows down the transition. By the way, a response delay of 100 milliseconds or less is not perceivable to a human brain.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I use MGWT TouchPanel and as far as I know it does not have the 300ms delay.

Comment: Andrei's confusion is understandable - your question talked about a couple of milliseconds, but your comment is referring to 300ms - that's a huge difference.

Comment: Well I do not know exactly how much time it takes but I know it is slower than native.